# Concatenate values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I have table row that I'm building in JavaScript. This row has an onClick function. I have to pass some values in this function but I'm getting an error. I think that my single and double quotes do not match. Here is my code:

```
insRow.innerHTML = "<tr><td><img src='../images/delete.png' border='0px' alt='Delete' title='Delete' onclick='pgDelete('"+fnObj.DATA+"','"+dType+"','"+tblID+"');' /></td></tr>";
```

Error message:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'
```

If I inspect the element in dev tools this is what I get:

```
<img src="../images/delete.png" alt="Delete" title="Delete" onclick="pgDelete(" 8739','att','dba');'="" border="0px">
```

If anyone can help with this problem please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Is this HTML injected with Javascript? If so, what does that code look like?

Comment: Well, look at it like a parser; you get to `onclick='`, so you're thinking, "they're using the single quote as a delimiter, so I'll stop at the next one". The next one is right after the opening parenthesis. The rest is garbage.

Comment: Yes this is injected with Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

`onclick='pgDelete('"+fnObj.DATA+"','"+dType+"','"+tblID+"');'`

into

`onclick='pgDelete(\""+fnObj.DATA+"\",\""+dType+"\",\""+tblID+"\");'`

Answer (score 0):

As a personal rule, I use `"double quotes"` for HTML and `'single quotes'` for JS.

It means:

```
<img src="../images/delete.png" border="0px" alt="Delete" title="Delete" onclick="pgDelete(fnObj.DATA + ',' + dType + ',' + tblID);" />
```

However, there is a tip for concatenation using `','`: use [Array.join()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

```
<img src="../images/delete.png" border="0px" alt="Delete" title="Delete" onclick="pgDelete([fnObj.DATA, dType, tblID].join());" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you're trying to concatenate but it seems like you have your parameters with unnecessary quotes and pluses. Does `pgDelete()` accept 3 parameters?

Try:
`onclick='pgDelete(fnObj.DATA,dType,tblID);'`

Instead of:
`onclick='pgDelete('"+fnObj.DATA+"','"+dType+"','"+tblID+"');'`

It would be helpful to see the origin of `fnObj.DATA` , `dType` and `tblID`; `pgDelete()` too.

Comment: All three arguments I will get once my process is successful. Ajax call send s parameters to the server. Then I get response in JSON format. I loop through object and populate values in each table row.